# Display product variations from woocommerce rest API on a React application

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

So, I'm trying to display on my react app the different variations of a product in dynamic dropdowns.

```
"variations": [
        {
            "id": 224,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "Size",
                    "option": "For iPhone XR"
                },
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "Color",
                    "option": "yellow"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 223,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "Size",
                    "option": "For iPhone 8Plus"
                },
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "Color",
                    "option": "yellow"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 222,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "Size",
                    "option": "For iPhone 8"
                },
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "name": "Color",
                    "option": "green"
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

I got this array of variations and I want each attribute on an individual dropdown and when I change the value of some of the dropdowns it will show only variations that have that value in common.

eg: let say that I have selected the size of "For iPhone XR" then on the color dropdown only show the "yellow" or if I select the "green" color only display "For iPhone 8" on the size dropdown.

I really have been trying to find a way to do it but I am in a point where I can't think of anything. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I am right there with you. Have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: @jped I was able to solve it, don't know if it's the ideal solution but it is working for what  I need, take a look and it might help you: https://github.com/engelcalderon/variations-wp-react

Comment: @Freddie Great! I need this too. So when i add the <Variation variations={variation}/> component, my page looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/BEGlPzz.png, what i am doing wrong?